# Heroku serves assets very slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, sprockets

I'm having huge trouble serving assets in my Rails application .Loading a 2KB image on my VPS (served directly by nginx, not Rails) takes me 42ms. Loading it on Heroku might take more than 1 minute sometimes.

The strange fact is that at this point the application is just a bunch of static pages served through High Voltage.

All my assets are precompiled locally. I have the rails_12factor and heroku_rails_deflate gems installed.

Here's my Sprockets configuration:

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages/home.js )
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true
```

Do you have any ideas?

Here's an excerpt from my logs:

```
14-07-11T23:48:54.917535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/pages/home-dca14429ad8cf7d73be6230207124ab1.js" host=v2-interconn.herokuapp.com request_id=aefbec46-f505-45b9-b368-1ad5f7924c70 fwd="188.10.253.161" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=3 status=200 bytes=916
2014-07-11T23:48:54.911470+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-a6b582f07af35ba97eef7b73812c37b9.js" host=v2-interconn.herokuapp.com request_id=3cf43d9f-e35b-4f62-8cbc-47121e07375b fwd="188.10.253.161" dyno=web.1 connect=0 service=8 status=200 bytes=917
2014-07-11T23:48:54.940930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/ballicons/letter-0223f57c4a985183df154ed1219f260e.svg" host=v2-interconn.herokuapp.com request_id=6c7a7b12-683e-42e7-9975-6ee58b17821e fwd="188.10.253.161" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=2 status=200 bytes=940
2014-07-11T23:48:55.064240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/ballicons/laptop-5ac5cd546c687e0bbba1e4043c5f62f8.svg" host=v2-interconn.herokuapp.com request_id=9a659d8b-8998-4f02-b8b3-edd1a6cfb34c fwd="188.10.253.161" dyno=web.1 connect=3 service=3 status=200 bytes=940
```

### Edit

The issue has been [resolved](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163) by Heroku. Thanks to all who helped! :)

Comment: This is plain bad, you need to fix it. Are you sure your heroku app is running in production mode? Check with `heroku config`, perhaps it's running in staging environment? Maybe you are still using webrick server?

Comment: Heroku is running in production and I use Thin as web server.

Comment: support can't help you? they should have more insight about their systems

Comment: I've opened a ticket. Hope they have at least an idea of what might be going on.

Comment: Possibly related to my similar [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717495/slow-page-load-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found information on Twitter that fixed my similar issue

this seems to be related to websockets.  Disabling it seems to cure the issues.

```
heroku labs:disable websockets -a myapp -p production
```

this makes it work as it used to, though the logs now look different :)

thanks to @dwaynemac @stephane_tavera on twitter.

**EDIT**:

Heroku shows this as a resolve issue, but answer applies in case it happens again.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163

Comment: Working great now. Apparently it was a temporary issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: Good to see you got it fixed!!

Answer (score 1):

**Heroku**

The only recommendation I could give would be to perhaps put the image on a third party service, [such as `S3`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)?

Heroku itself is hosted on the Amazon AWS platform, so serving the assets will not be 
of any issue. All the times I've used Heroku (a [good demo being here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com)), our assets load as fast as we need them

[image]

--

**DB**

The one thing I've found with Heroku is if your DB connection sucks, you'll have no chance of loading your pages quickly.

The `db` connection is the Achilles Heel of Heroku - unless you use Heroku's own [`postgres` db](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), you'll have to make sure you have a fast connection

Other than that - the best thing to do is provide your logs for us to look through!

Comment: I'm using Heroku's database and the logs don't show anything strange. I've added an excerpt to the question.