# Slow Page load on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails 4 app on heroku. I'm relatively new to both.

Every page I load or ajax I execute takes 1 minute. Always no matter when.

I thought it had to do with ajax calls because I an visually see when the DOM is loaded fully better, but it really is any page that I grab from heroku

To test this I made a test page, which consists of

```
<h2>test</h2>
a test page
```

**No layout, No CSS no anything else**, no html or body tag, just an H2 tag and some text, thats the entirety of what is served.

So, right after i put the URL in the browser and hit enter.  I see the heroku logs -t jump to life and I see the request being processed

```
2014-07-12T21:07:36.149964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pages/test" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=490be219-e72b-4df3-879b-9060b2b5140a fwd="my.ip.add.ress" dyno=web.1 connect=12 service=11 status=200 bytes=1049
2014-07-12T21:07:36.136011+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/test" for my.ip.add.ress at 2014-07-12 21:07:36 +0000
2014-07-12T21:07:36.141517+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/test.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-07-12T21:07:36.139697+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#test as HTML
2014-07-12T21:07:36.141690+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

All, good so far, everything processed and ready in 2ms.  But the page does not load entirely.  I can see the text on the screen already.  But the browsers "waiting" spinner is still going.

> 5.32s (onload: 1m 5s)

Finally it loads. 1 minute later.  It does this with all pages.  Which really affects AJAX since the redraws wont happen until the pages is fully loaded.

What is going on and how do I stop it? Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look in the "Network" tab of your browser debug tools? You may find some external JS, CSS, or other slow asset is causing your delayed load.

Comment: I have looked but there is nothing.  What i showed above is the entire html an H2 tag and some text, there is no CSS, no JS, no anything.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're not using a layout to render this view?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I think it may be a transient Heroku problem which started last night for me. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708085/heroku-serves-assets-very-slowly) might be related.

Comment: correct there is no layout.  i turned it off for this test page to reduce the number of variables with this issue.  as you see with the heroko log only this single page is served. and browser view source confirms, an H2 tag and a bit of text.

Comment: @user3009816 thanks i saw that post when searching but didnt realize it also happened in the last 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

I found information on Twitter.

this seems to be related to websockets.  Disabling it seems to cure the issues.

```
heroku labs:disable websockets -a myapp -p production
```

this makes it work as it used to, though the logs now look different :)

**EDIT**:

Heroku shows this as a resolve issue, but answer applies in case it happens again.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163

Comment: I think the problem has now been resolved. My app is back working without any intervention on my part.

Comment: mine as well. their status page confirms as well

Comment: Hello, where does this line go exactly? New to this and trying to make a python data app load faster. Thank you!